# Partitioning incompletely specified error in my spark application

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

Please take a look at this code below .
   I am getting error for the below code when I pass value for the number of partitions.

```
      def loadDataFromPostgress(sqlContext: SQLContext, tableName: String, 
         columnName: String, dbURL: String, userName: String, pwd: String, 
         partitions: String): DataFrame = {
        println("the no of partitions are : "+partitions)
        var dataDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
        scala.collection.Map("url" -> dbURL,
                          "dbtable" -> tableName,
                      "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
                   "user" -> userName,
                 "password" -> pwd,
                   "partitionColumn" -> columnName,
               "numPartitions" -> "1000")).load()
                return dataDF
                        }
```

**error:**

```
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Partitioning incompletely specified
                App > at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
                App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:38)
                App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:315)
                App > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    App > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
                App > at Test$.loadDataFromGreenPlum(script.scala:28)
                App > at Test$.loadDataFrame(script.scala:15)
                App > at Test$.main(script.scala:59)
                App > at Test.main(script.scala)
                App > at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native 
                  Method)
                App > at
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check code below how exactly you can use.

```
def loadDataFromPostgress(sqlContext: SQLContext, tableName: String,
                            columnName: String, dbURL: String, userName: String,
                            pwd: String, partitions: String): DataFrame = {
    println("the no of partitions are : " + partitions)
    val dataDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
      scala.collection.Map("url" -> dbURL,
        "dbtable" -> "(select mod(tmp.empid,10)  as hash_code,tmp.* from employee as tmp) as t",
        "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "user" -> userName,
        "password" -> pwd,
        "partitionColumn" -> hash_code,
        "lowerBound" -> 0,
        "upperBound" -> 10
    "numPartitions" -> "10"
    ) ).load()
    dataDF
  }
```

Above code will create 10 tasks with 10 queries as shown below.
Before that job will find out

> offset = (upperBound-lowerBound)/numPartitions

Here `offset = (10-0)/10 = 1`

```
select mod(tmp.empid,10)  as hash_code,tmp.* from employee as tmp where hash_code between 0 between 1
select mod(tmp.empid,10)  as hash_code,tmp.* from employee as tmp where hash_code between 1 between 2
.
.
select mod(tmp.empid,10)  as hash_code,tmp.* from employee as tmp where hash_code between 9 between 10
```

This will create 10 partitions and

empid ends with 0 will be going one partition as mod(empid,10) always equals 0

empid ends with 1 will be going one partition as mod(empid,10) always equals 1

like this all employee rows will be spitted into 10 partitions.

you have to change partitionColumn,upperBound,lowerBound,numPartitions values according to your requirements.

Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning requires:

- partitioning column (integer).
- number of columns
- lower bound for the column
- upper bound for the column

The last two are missing, and this is why you get the error.