# Performance issue in spark java

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.11 version and I am doing only 3 basic operations in my application:

1. taking records from the database: 2.2 million
2. checking records from a file (5 000) present in Database(2.2 million) using contains
3. writing matched records to a file of CSV format

But for these 3 operations, it takes almost 20 minutes. If I do same operations in SQL, it will take less than 1 minutes.

I have started to use spark because it will yield results very fast but it is taking too much of time. How to improve performance?

Step 1: taking records from the database.

```
        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.put("user", "test");
        connectionProperties.put("password", "test##");
        String query="(SELECT * from items)
        dataFileContent= spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.20.0.11/devad", query,connectionProperties);
```

Step2: checking records of file A (5k) present in file B (2M) using contains

```
Dataset<Row> NewSet=source.join(target,target.col("ItemIDTarget").contains(source.col("ItemIDSource")),"inner");
```

Step3: writing matched records to a file of CSV format

```
 NewSet.repartition(1).select("*")
        .write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("delimiter", ",")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")  
        .option("nullValue", "")  
        .save(fileAbsolutePath);
```

To improve the performance I have tried several things like setting Cache, 
data serialization

```
set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")),
```

Shuffle time

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10"),
```

Data Structure Tuning

```
-XX:+UseCompressedOops ,
```

none of the approaches is not yielding better performance.

Comment: Is there a reason to use spark for this use case? It would seem to me that writing the 5k records to the DB and issuing a SQL join within the DB would be the most efficient approach.

Comment: I mean, how long it takes to materialize this query into Spark: `SELECT * from items)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increasing performance is more like improving parallelism.

Parallelism depends on number of partitions in RDD.

Make sure Dataset/Dataframe/RDD neither have too many number of partitions nor very less number of partitions.

Please check below suggestions where you can improve your code.  I'm more comfortable with scala so I am providing suggestions in scala.

Step1:
Make sure you have control on connections you make with database by mentionioning numPartitions.

Number of connections = number of partitions.

Below I just assigned 10 to num_partitions, this you have to tune to get more performance.

```
  int num_partitions;
  num_partitions = 10;
  Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
  connectionProperties.put("user", "test");
  connectionProperties.put("password", "test##");
  connectionProperties.put("partitionColumn", "hash_code");
  String query = "(SELECT  mod(A.id,num_partitions)  as hash_code, A.* from items A)";
  dataFileContent = spark.read()
    .jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.20.0.11/devad",
      dbtable = query,
      columnName = "hash_code",
      lowerBound = 0,
      upperBound = num_partitions,
      numPartitions = num_partitions,
      connectionProperties);
```

[You can check how numPartitions works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427885/partitioning-incompletely-specified-error-in-my-spark-application/43429353#43429353)

Step2:

```
  Dataset<Row> NewSet = source.join(target,
    target.col("ItemIDTarget").contains(source.col("ItemIDSource")),
    "inner");
```

Since one of table/dataframe having 5k records(small amount of data) you can use broadcast join as mentioned below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val joined_df = largeTableDF.join(broadcast(smallTableDF), "key")
```

Step3: 
Use  coalesce to decrease number of partitions so that it  avoids full shuffle.

```
NewSet.coalesce(1).select("*")
        .write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("delimiter", ",")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")  
        .option("nullValue", "")  
        .save(fileAbsolutePath);
```

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Good one, probably `fetchsize` option could be in the list. This option influence behavior of fetching a number of rows per round trip. Caution: _Too high number may lead to OOM exception._